# JQuery ajaxForm plugin 'xhr.responseText' returns only the "body" part in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform

Trying to load a page with Jquery after submitting a form using the [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin and even though it works as expected in Chrome and Firefox, in Internet Explorer the `xhr.responseText` variable returns only what's in the `<body>` part of the response web-page and not the whole page page with head, script, css, etc. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
},
    complete: function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText); //this is just to see what's inside the xhr.responseText...
    }

});
```

**EDIT:** Ok, I figured out part of the problem - this only occurs when the form is encoded as `enctype = 'multipart/form-data'` and/or it has an `<input type='file' />` and only in Internet Explorer, but I still have no clue how to make it work for those types of forms....

Comment: which version of jquery/plugins your'r using. the callback is 'complete' not `success : fucntion(){ }`?

Comment: @ai.farfa - JQuery v1.7.1, what do you mean by the callback is 'complete' - 'complete is what I have written in the code above..

Comment: Ok, I figured out part of the problem - this only occurs when the form is encoded as `enctype = 'multipart/form-data'` and/or it has an `<input type='file' />` and only in IE, but still no clue how to make it work for those types of forms....